# Why am I getting a syntax error, after making a long string of code into a function?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

I'm still new to programming python but have a nice little tool that I use at work. The original code I wrote would go into a csv file, and set certain columns to be a list. The code was functioning, and is as follows:

```
with open('profiles.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for column in reader:
        numbers.append(column[0])
del numbers[0]
with open('profiles.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for column in reader:
        devlist.append(column[0])        
del devlist[0]
```

I decided to task myself with cleaning the code up as I became more familiar with functions, but this code will not work:

```
def getInfo(keyword, columnvar):
    with open('profiles.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for column in reader:
            '%s'.append(column['%s']) % (keyword, columnvar)
        del '%s'['%s'] % (keyword, columnvar)
getInfo(numbers, 0)
getInfo(devlist, 0)
```

I do not get what the issue is, as I copied the formatting of the original code exactly. If I do not put quotes around the %s, I get

```
    %s.append(column[%s]) % (keyword, columnvar)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However, if I add quotes, I get

```
    del '%s'['%s'] % (keyword, columnvar)
SyntaxError: can't delete operator
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with `del keyword[columnvar]`?

Comment: You are trying to do something wrong with '%s'.append(...), because 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Answer (score 1):

You cannot replace objects by strings of the same name. Here is a simple example where you are going wrong:

```
>>> l = [1,2] # a list
>>> l.append(3) # append an item; succeeds
>>> '%s'.append(4) % l
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

l is a list object, but when you try to do something like `'%s'%l`, it becomes a string object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you somewhat misunderstood the `%` operator. It just formats a string (And BTW, you should use `str.format` for that). What you're trying to do here is formatting the string, then `eval()` it (which is a bad practice!).

What you want for a correct syntax is:

```
for column in reader:
    keyword.append(column[columnvar])
del keyword[columnvar]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I do not get what the issue is, as I copied the formatting of the original code exactly

That code is not syntactically valid.  Python's pretty dynamic, but it's not *that* dynamic.  Note that there is a way to make it that dynamic, but that's not really what you should be doing here.

> However, if I add quotes ...

This, too, is not valid syntax.  The '`%s`' and other substitutions work only within `string`s, and arbitrary `string`s are not executed as a part of your program.  Python does lexical analysis of your entire program's text (at exec/import time).  The syntax you've chosen is not valid.

With respect to:

```
del numbers[0]
del devlist[0]
```

...we're doing cleanup, here, yes?  Let's try `csv`'s features here.  [`Sniffer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer) can tell you whether there's a header row.  And [`DictReader`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) can allow you to index those fields by the header column's name.  That way you can skip this bit entirely.